# Soft body self collision BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, soft-body, collision

I've got the model of a hand fully rigged and programmed with a python controller, but I can't find a way to make it collide with itself, so the fingers won't "perforate" the hand.

I am in Blender Game, and the mesh is configured as Soft Body and added boundaries, but it keeps acting the same.

[image: Configuration]

Is there a way to make it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really do that with softbody? Why? usually fingers are animated via armature and playing an action.

Comment: It is rigged, the point is that I need the mesh to collide with itself, so I used softbody because in the blender manual says that only soft bodies can collide with themselves. I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this manual talks about Blender soft body rather than BGE soft body. These are two separate things (and not compatible). I haven't seen a self-collision option at the BGE soft body. As you already rigged the mesh the armature takes over ALL poses. There is no need for soft body, especially not at the fingers. Just play the action.

Comment: The api says that only softbody can collide with themselves and that's true but it referes collision between two or more objects not to self collision. ;)